# Modelling a scalable grid trading bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, orleans

I implemented a simple grid trading strategy using Akka actors and I wanted to try Microsoft Orleans for improved scalability and as a learning opportunity for Kubernetes (k8s), Azure Container Registry (ACR) and Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

My strategy involves representing each grid bot as a grain. Each grain would wrap a WebSocket client connection to an exchange, which could potentially allow a grain to be activated in a random pod. This setup would be part of a cluster spanning several machines, where grid bots with varying API keys and parameters (such as lower limit, upper limit, and grid count) could be spawned in random pods.

However, I've been unable to find conclusive information regarding the feasibility and efficiency of wrapping an open WebSocket connection using Microsoft Orleans grains. What's your opinion? Have someone used it for a similar use case, I know there are a lot of Charge EV apps out there.

For reference, the grid trading strategy is explained in more detail here: [Grid Bots: What is it and how does it work?](https://help.3commas.io/en/articles/3583109-grid-bots-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work)

Thinking loudly but can a bot be represented by a console application which can be invoked with all input parameters (environment variables?). We can build in into a docker image using Dockerfile and can be deployed as a pod? Does bot instance per container sounds inefficient, or even impossible because I would like to have an ASP.NET Core minimal API endpoint which spawns grid bots, what do you think?

Or perhaps I should keep it modelled as classic Akka actors, have a BotManager which is monitoring and managing the bots that are running on multiple threads within the same ASP.NET Core Web API application. Then build a docker image for that ASP.NET Core Web API using Dockerfile. Run multiple instances of it and let nginx reverse proxy route the traffic to the instance with less amount of overhead?

```cs
app.MapPost("/startBot", (BotManager botManager, PlaceGridRequest request) =>
{
    var bot = botManager.StartNewBot(request);
    return Results.Accepted(new { BotId = bot.Id });
});

app.MapDelete("/stopBot/{botId}", (BotManager botManager, Guid botId) =>
{
    if (botManager.TryStopBot(botId))
    {
        return Results.NoContent();
    }

    return Results.NotFound();
});

app.MapGet("/activeBots", (BotManager botManager) =>
{
    var activeBots = botManager.GetActiveBots();
    return Results.Ok(activeBots);
});
```

Comment: If you have a model that already works with Akka.NET, why not just scale out using [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-sharding.html)? Works nearly identically to Orleans' virtual actor model.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb, I wanted to compare Akka.NET, Proto.Actor and Microsoft Orleans for learning purposes but looks like Orleans is not good for my use case because each bot is basically an open websocket connection to an exchange and grains are shortlived, so looks like I would now be comparing Akka.NET and Proto.Actor's solutions. I have to read more about Akka.Cluster.Sharding because in Proto.Actor's solution I believe it's best to build the whole API into a docker image and deploy to ACR and use ConfigMap for env and ingress for routing

Comment: I just had a look at Akka.Cluster.Sharding and it seems like it's useful when you need idempotency. In my case, the grid bot actors got a few children actors but they are not supposed to talk to each other, which means I shouldn't make it more complicated than it actually is. The 2nd advantage seems to be the automatic actor load distribution between nodes and also actor deduplication (to make sure only one unique actor is there). Is that correct and did I miss something?

Comment: Tbh, I also tried to code the same grid strategy without an actor framework, using MediatR's INotification for the event-driven architecture because I didn't want to use EventHandlers, also used commands for placing limit/market orders on the market. MediatR is an in-memory event bus which I believe makes it nearly identical to the internal communication of Proto.Actor/Akka.NET. MediatR's DI registration is painful and also thread management too.

Comment: My API acts as a bot manager, spawns/stops/monitors multiple active bots and the point is each bot to be multithreaded which is coming out of box with the actor framework. Another advantage would be If an exception gets thrown somewhere each particular bot actor has its own middleware (supervision strategy) to catch the exception and restart only that particular actor while in MediatR the exception middleware would be globally defined and make things harder for me.

Comment: Also the potential concurrency issues in MediatR just because we can't tell which threads will be managing which bots makes things scarier. To recap, I believe the classic actors are totally worth it for this use case but grains aren't.

Comment: Forgot to tell that I don't really need a distributed event bus because bots will never to talk to each other, so I don't need RabbitMQ, whatever. An in-memory event bus like the one used for internal communication or MediatR is a perfect fit